# Why doesn't java.lang.Short have a reverse() method similar to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, api, integer, short

Why doesn't java.lang.Short (or Float or Double) class have a reverse method similar to java.lang.Integer ?

They both do have reverseBytes method though.

Why isn't the API list consistent ?

short can hold 2 bytes and it would have made sense to have a reverse method as well. 
Wouldn't it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree on the API criticism, it's pretty simple to emulate:

```
short input = ...;
short reversed = (short)(Integer.reverse(input) >> 16);
```

So maybe the answer is:

1. Not enough people felt it was necessary
2. It's easy enough to simulate
3. Someone wanted to show off with the implementation of `Integer.reverse()`
4. Every line of code needs to maintained. Less code == less bugs, lower cost, easier maintenance.

Comment: +1 Perhaps Byte.reverse() for consistency ;)